# Reading numbers from CSV file and calculating the average

Tags: c#, .net, csv, average, textfieldparser

I need help taking numbers from a CSV file and calculating the average. So far I can retrieve the correct numbers from the last column, but it seems like I am not converting them to right type of array. I think the number I am looking for should be `Average = 6.4`.

```csharp
private void label21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = conf.path + "\\" + "CloudOpen.csv"; 

    using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
        csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
        csvParser.ReadLine();

        while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
        {
            // Read current line fields, pointer moves to the next line.
            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
            string five = fields[5]; 
            var intArray = five.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray(); 

            Average(intArray);
        }
    }
}

public void Average(int[] array)
{
    double avg = Queryable.Average(array.AsQueryable());

    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + avg);
}
```

Here is the CSV file I am reading:

```csv
Id,time,two,five,ten,twenty
0,03/07/2022 14:47:03,0,1,2,5
0,03/07/2022 14:47:33,0,1,2,6
0,03/07/2022 14:48:37,0,1,3,6
0,03/07/2022 14:48:37,0,1,3,6
0,03/07/2022 14:48:37,0,1,3,7
0,03/07/2022 14:48:37,0,1,3,8
```

Comment: Integers can’t store floating point values

Comment: Use TryParse to get a converted value

Comment: Seems like you are overcomplicating things. Keep a running total and then calculate the average at the end.

Comment: I reverted your ["working code" edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71396522/3) because you fixed the code that is the premise of the question.  _Don't do that_; when you replace the broken code in a question with fixed code it will no longer make sense for future readers.  Instead, if an answer was posted that largely addressed or explained the problem for you then you should accept it as the solution; otherwise, it's perfectly acceptable to post and accept your own answer.  Also, in editing your code you also undid the formatting fixes I made, which someone else then had to fix again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void average()

        {

            List<double> listA = new List<double>();

            int five;

            var path = conf.path + "\\" + "CloudOpen.csv"; 

            using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))

            {

                csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };

                csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

                csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

                csvParser.ReadLine();

                while (!csvParser.EndOfData)

                {
                    string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();

                    five = fields[5].Count();
   
                    var fi = Convert.ToInt32(fields[5]);

                    listA.Add(fi);

                }

                int total = listA.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

                var count = listA.Count;

                Console.WriteLine("Numbers added:" + total);

                Console.WriteLine("Number of items:" + listA.Count);

                Console.WriteLine(total / count);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a .NET 6.0 command line project you can run the following code without worrying about namespaces, classes, etc. I believe you may need to either round to one decimal or use the ceiling for your use case?

```
//Add six values to list of integers (simplifying the CSV to Array code)
List<int> listInts = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8 };

double avg = Queryable.Average(listInts.AsQueryable()); //This variable will be a double of 6.333 repeating
double avgOneDecimal = Math.Round(avg, 1); //This variable will round to one decimal place
double avgOneDecimalCeiling = Math.Ceiling(avg); //This variable will be 7 if you need to round up for whatever reason

Console.WriteLine($"Average = {avg}");
Console.WriteLine($"Average to one decimal = {avgOneDecimal}");
Console.WriteLine($"Average rounded up = {avgOneDecimalCeiling}");
```